# Missing Status Bar in PowerGUI

Tags: powershell, powergui

I am missing the bar in PowerGUI that has all the key buttons on it e.g. Debug, Save, New, Open etc.

Is there anyway to get it back? I have looked on Google to no avail. 
(Ps. The bar with 'File', 'Edit', 'View' etc. is also missing.)

Comment: In most Windows apps if you press and release ALT key the file menu bar appears even if its hidden.

Comment: Also have you tried this? http://sebmatthews.net/2013/08/powergui-menu-bar-vanished-look-no-further/

Comment: No luck im afraid. Also, with the link you mentioned, I couldn't find the file in which the author was pointing me to :(

Comment: I'd suggest to rename folder `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Quest Software\PowerGUI`.

Comment: Hey guys. i just realised that 'AppData' was a hidden folder. Woops! All is fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already figured this out, but I thought I would suggest a more straightforward fix in case anyone sees this in the future.

There is a setting to hide the Menu Bar, though it won't usually let you deselect it.

Try this:

1. Right click on one of the remaining toolbars (over the Save button,
   for example).
2. Click Customize, then the Toolbars tab.
3. If the Menu Bar option is not selected, select it

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsJb7.png) (Not enough rep. to post an image here, yet.)

Answer (score 0):

in the PowerShell window press alt+space > choose settings > appearance tab in the left> turn off "Hide the title bar" and close the PowerShell and reopen it.
these dummy steps worked for me.